# Default path in OS 12 terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I tried to install Pygame was n my iMac OS 12 in Terminal using the information on this site : 
http://brysonpayne.com/2015/01/10/setting-up-pygame-on-a-mac/

When I got to step 4 , installing Home Brew  it didn’t work. 
I decided to forget the idea for now , however now im now having issues with Terminal . 
    Most specific the Ls command comes back as 
-bash ls command not found 
    From what I have read it seems that I changed the default file path in Terminal , I don’t know how to fix this.
    I’m hoping someone has an answer.

```
Thanks 
John
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer:
    export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"

I typed this in and lo and behold it was fixed !!!